# Identity Toolkit unrecognized config parameter

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

The following error shows up when  I run the gitkit widget:

```
[  0.004s] [identitytoolkit] Invalid config: "callbackUrl"rj @ gitkit.js:236pj.addLogRecord @ gitkit.js:236Li.log @ gitkit.js:219Q @ gitkit.js:236zl @ gitkit.js:273(anonymous function) @ gitkit.js:306(anonymous function) @ gitkit-widget.html?mode=select:29
```

My code is the following:

```
var config = {
            signInSuccessUrl: "/",
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAt3gELMqBCdn9U8FLSXbtCJbizHSX3kng",
            siteName: "Google Apps Training",
            signInOptions: ["google","facebook", "microsoft"],
            //idps: ["google", "facebook", "microsoft"],
            /*callbacks: {
                signInSuccess: function(tokenString, accountInfo, signInSuccessUrl) {

                    console.log("callback");
                    console.log(tokenString);
                    console.log(accountInfo);
                    console.log(signInSuccessUrl);

                    return true;
                }
            },*/
            callbackUrl: "http://localhost:8080/signin"
        };

        // The HTTP POST body should be escaped by the server to prevent XSS
        window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
                '#gitkitWidgetDiv', // accepts any CSS selector
                config);
```

Here is the gitkit documentation sample available at https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend

```
var config = {
          apiKey: 'AIza...',
          signInSuccessUrl: '/',
          signInOptions: ["google", "password"],
          oobActionUrl: '/',
          siteName: 'this site',

          // Optional - function called after sign in completes and before
          // redirecting to signInSuccessUrl. Return false to disable
          // redirect.
          // callbacks: {
          //  signInSuccess: function(tokenString, accountInfo,
          //    opt_signInSuccessUrl) {
          //      return true;
          //    }
          // },

          // Optional - key for query parameter that overrides
          // signInSuccessUrl value (default: 'signInSuccessUrl')
          // queryParameterForSignInSuccessUrl: 'url'

          // Optional - URL of site ToS (linked and req. consent for signup)
          // tosUrl: 'http://example.com/terms_of_service',

          // Optional - URL of callback page (default: current url)
          // callbackUrl: 'http://example.com/callback',

          // Optional - Cookie name (default: gtoken)
          //            NOTE: Also needs to be added to config of the ‘page with
          //                  sign in button’. See above
          // cookieName: ‘example_cookie’,

           // Optional - UI configuration for accountchooser.com
           /*acUiConfig: {
               title: 'Sign in to example.com',
               favicon: 'http://example.com/favicon.ico',
               branding: 'http://example.com/account_choooser_branding'
           },
           */

           // Optional - Function to send ajax POST requests to your Recover URL
           //            Intended for CSRF protection, see Advanced Topics
           //      url - URL to send the POST request to
           //     data - Raw data to include as the body of the request
           //completed - Function to call with the object that you parse from
           //            the JSON response text. {} if no response
           /*ajaxSender: function(url, data, completed) {
                         },
           */
      };
      // The HTTP POST body should be escaped by the server to prevent XSS
      window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
          '#gitkitWidgetDiv', // accepts any CSS selector
          config,
          'JAVASCRIPT_ESCAPED_POST_BODY');
```

So, if the most recent sample code shows "callbackUrl" as an available optional parameter, why gitkit js does not recognizes it as valid?

Is there a place where I can check all the available parameters?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The callbackUrl is no longer a valid field. The documentation is incorrect and will be updated promptly. We apologize for that and we thank you for bringing this up to us. The widget current url will be automatically used as the IDP callback url so be sure to add your widget url in your IDP (google, facebook, etc) oauth client setup (callback url).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about if I'm using Google Endpoints and I would  like to redirect the callback to one of the endpoints? Is this still possible? Is there any sample code available online that uses Google Endpoints?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you are redirecting to the google endpoints, you have the choice of specifying that url in the gitkit config field: signInSuccessUrl or redirecting manually via the sign in success callback function.